# PHP link issue with target="_blank"

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have a strange issue in PHP + HTML.

I made this code to auto generate an item image and create a `<a>` tag with `_blank` target. Works nicelly, but the link doesn't target in a blank page.

**PHP**

```
<?php if ($item->getPrimaryImage()) :?>
<div class="image-container">
    <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?><a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php endif; ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryImage()->getSource(); ?>" alt="" class="mosaic-image" />
                </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should show the corresponding part of your generated html code. It could be that there is something wrong with the `$item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl();`, returning something that is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bad way of opening links in new windows as it is somewhat depreciated. Use javascript instead, here's an example:

`<a href="mylink.htm" onclick="window.open('mylink.htm');return false;">click me</a>`

returning false after opening the window stops the current page changing too, but allows to to keep your SEO context with the regular `href=""` attribute.

Comment: While `_blank` is still valid according to the [htlm5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword) it is most of the time a bad idea to not let the user choose by himself if the link should be opened in a new window or not. Replacing `target="_blank"` with js - if you e.g. want to perform a `window.open` - that does not check if target `_blank` was removed e.g. by a plugin, is way worser, because it makes it definitely impossible to suppress that behavior.

Comment: @t.niese I know it's still in the html5 spec, but I believe it has been deprecated as of XHTML 1.0 Strict and XHTML 1.1 and is basically on the way out. As for the user experience, this is a different subject, and different needs require different approaches. In a web-app for instance, this might not be a concern.

Comment: The original movement from `html4` to `XHTML 1.x` was _stopped_ in favor of `html5` being the new standard, because of the restrictions of `XHTML` and the stalled development of `XHTML 2`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a php-issue. There is nothing wrong with the code, the same output was created in this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3e65q/

```
<div class="image-container">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">hello</a>
</div>
```

And it opens in a new window (new tab in my case), but it works as expected.

Comment: `_new` and  `_blank` are not the same.  `_blank`  has a special meaning (open the link in a new window/tab), `_new` not (it will open the link in a window with the target name `_new`).

Comment: t.niese I wanted to write _blank in the example, but reading another answer I made my mind a mess. Thanks for the comment.